# CSS Vertical Spacing Issue (Margin?) - Vertical Space Between Two Divs

Tags: html, css, web

I've got the layout of my site mostly done. On the domain I'm testing this layout on - http://networkgenius.org/ - there is a vertical space separating the content-wrapper div and the menu div. I have the margins set to 0px for the vertical spacing, and this is the only area that is separated like it is.

I'd like the white content area to be pressed up right against the bottom of the menu, so that none of the body's background shows between them.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your navigation bar (`#nav, #nav ul`) has a height of `35px` on it, but it seems like the background image isn't actually that tall, and since you seem to have set it to only `repeat-x` with a `transparent` color, you'll get that space.

Set it to `27px` or smaller and you'll be fine (in Chrome, at least).

Comment: Ah, I never thought to look at the elements inside the divs. That did it!

Thank you!

-Sootah

Answer (score 1):

Jeff is right.  Your #nav ul has a height larger than your navbar (and background image).  Also, there is vertical padding on the nav ul as well that adds to the discrepancy.